# Take Pivot Low/High and draw trendline

Tags: pivot

I am trying to take the most recent last two Pivot High points (and Low) and draw a trendline from the last Pivot High to the current Pivot high.  Since the pivothigh() function has the left and right bars both set to 5 I can always assume my currect Pivot point is bar_index[5].  The problem I am having is how do I keep up the with last pivot point that came before the current pivot?  Not sure if there is some way when a pivot point is reached and labeled on the chart you can somehow save that candle time so you can reference it in the line.new() function.  Here is my current code but the following code is what I manually did to figure out the last pivot point. Instead of typing in 13 or 18 it should be a variable that holds the previous candle that was a pivot point.
**bar_index[13] - botc, low[18]**

````
showpivot = input(true, title="Show Pivot Points")
lb = input(5, title="Left Bars", minval=1)
rb = input(5, title="Right Bars", minval=1)

float top = na
float bot = na
top := pivothigh(lb, rb)
bot := pivotlow(lb, rb)

plotshape(top and showpivot, text="[PH]",  style=shape.labeldown, color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, location=location.abovebar, transp=0, offset = -rb)
plotshape(bot and showpivot, text="[PL]",  style=shape.labeldown, color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, location=location.belowbar, transp=0, offset = -rb)

topc = 0, botc = 0
topc := top ? lb : nz(topc[1]) + 1
botc := bot ? lb : nz(botc[1]) + 1

var line divl = na
var label lab = na

if bot and showpivot
    line.delete(divl)
    divl := line.new(bar_index[13] - botc, low[18], bar_index[5], low[lb] , color = color.lime, extend=extend.right)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found some code that answered my question

https://www.tradingview.com/script/eXUYLaGv-Trend-Lines-v2/